# Google Maps iOS / MySQL - Storing Route Travelled for Polyline

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, google-maps

My ride sharing app uses the Google Maps iOS SDK for Objective-C, and I'm currently able to draw a Polyline easily enough between a pickup/destination point.

However, I would like to be able to track the route that a driver takes on a trip, and (most importantly) somehow store this data in my MySQL backend, so that I can plot the actual route travelled on a Trip History View.

I can compile a huge array of locations hit on the route by using the didUpdateLocations delegate method, but how would I effectively store this in MySQL.

I realize I'm not posting any code and probably will be frowned upon for seeking a 'best practice' answer, but I'm pretty stuck on ideas. Thanks for your help.

Comment: "how would I effectively store this in MySQL" In a project of my own I am also working with lat and long to display them in google maps. The lat i save as decimal(10,8) and the long as decimal(11,8). These are the best values to save them as.

Comment: @Svenmarim thanks, however I am looking to save a massive array of lat/lngs to plot a route travelled. Any idea on how to best do that?